# libcurl: Determine whether a URL is in the same LAN

Tags: c++, c, libcurl

I'd like to know if it's at all possible to determine whether a particular URL belongs to the same LAN which the machine originating the request is from.

I mainly want to do this for security purposes at the level of the software which does HTTP requests, i.e. I want to disallow it even attempting to go outside of the network. I know such things are usually done at the level of network administration, but the question is about how to do this at the level of software.

I thought it might be possible to go the IP address way - e.g., resolve DNS, determine the IP address, and then see if it's in one of the local network classes (10.0.0.*, 192.168.*.*, etc.)

Does anyone have any idea / guess how to do this elegantly in C++ with possibly the usage of libcurl?

Thanks.

Comment: Like you say, this is totally wrong. Just configure your gateway/firewall not to let the requests in.